# Resolve url from inside template

Tags: url

Can I resolve full URL to some object - entry or category, from inside Twig template?

Mind you, I don't mean searching for something by slug, but by full URL. So, for example, instead of passing `'some-slug'` to function, i want to pass `'some-category/some-subcategory/some-slug'`.

I need to to this, because i want to create breadcrumbs links based on `craft.request.segments` object. So, i need to look up for entry object for `some-category`, then entry for `some-category/some-subcategory/` and then for `some-category/some-subcategory/some-slug` (well, i dont really need last one because its just page im on currently).

Comment: In most cases, Craft does this for you, and you'll have access to `{{ entry }}`, `{{ category }}`, etc. in your template, already. Where is this URI coming from?

Comment: I want to create breadcrumb links based on request segments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[According to the `EntryQuery` documentation](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/element-queries/entry-queries.html#parameters), you can search by URI.

The most basic use (searching by the complete URI) would look like this:

```
{% set entryWithUri = craft.entries({
  uri: craft.app.request.path | literal
}).one() %}
```

But to progressively dive into the segments (say, to create breadcrumbs like you mentioned), it takes a little more work:

```
{% set segments = craft.app.request.segments %}

{% for segment in segments %}
  {% set uriPart = segments[0:loop.index] %}

  {% set entryAtPath = craft.entries({
    uri: uriPart | join('/') | literal
  }).one() %}

  {% if entryAtPath %}
    {{ entryAtPath.link }}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Supposing `entryAtPath` is empty, you may then need to fall back to a Category query, then a Tag query, etc. Unfortunately, there isn't a great way to fetch across Element types—which would make this a little easier.

Comment: Great piece of code, thanks! I will be using it in my boilerplate template from now on. I would only change one thing - to decrease number of queries, i would add `if not loop.last` - last part of breadcrumb is always current category/entry so there is no need for query. One question - what does literal filter do in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Usually I have a {{baseUrl}} defined in config or .env available globally;
then {{baseUrl}}/{{entry.uri}}

Comment: I think the question is about how to _look up_ an entry by a full URI, not how to get the complete path/URI of an entry.

Comment: Yeas, thats what i want to do @AugustMiller